# How does NOW/DAY in a Solr query work?

Tags: solr

I am trying to figure out why Solr thinks an doc is in the past. My query is set up to use

`published:[* TO NOW/DAY]`

The doc I am hoping it will find has a published date of

```
2012-04-30T04:00:00Z
```

Current Solr server time is Mon Apr 30 18:26:47 EDT 2012. My understanding says that the document should have been found by now, which makes me think the NOW/DAY doesn't work the way I think it does. Does anybody know how the NOW/DAY evaluates dates and why when Solr is not finding my doc when I add that stipulation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`NOW/DAY` means take the actual date time and round it to the day (leaving out the time). Of course if the actual date is `2012-04-30`, any hour, the result is `2012-04-30T00:00:00Z`.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. What we did is switch the rule to `NOW/DAY+1` to make sure we catch anything published on said day.

Comment: Here is a useful reference: http://searchhub.org/2012/02/23/date-math-now-and-filter-queries/

Comment: The above link from @arun is no longer available.  This might be the same link, [Solr Date Math, NOW and filter queries](https://dzone.com/articles/solr-date-math-now-and-filter).

Answer (score 0):

Try just using NOW. I suspect that NOW/DAY is equal to 2012-04-30T00:00:00Z.

Answer (score 0):

`NOW/DAY` rounds down to midnight last night. If you want the midnight of current day change with `NOW+1DAY/DAY`.

> **Date Math Syntax**
>
> Date math expressions consist either adding some
>   quantity of time in a specified unit, or rounding the current time by
>   a specified unit. expressions can be chained and are evaluated left to
>   right.
>
> For example: this represents a point in time two months from
>   now:
>
> NOW+2MONTHS
>
> This is one day ago:
>
> NOW-1DAY
>
> A slash is used to indicate rounding. This represents the beginning of the current hour:
>
> NOW/HOUR
>
> The following example computes (with millisecond precision)
>   the point in time six months and three days into the future and then
>   rounds that time to the beginning of that day:
>
> NOW+6MONTHS+3DAYS/DAY
>
> Note that while date math is most commonly used relative to NOW it can
>   be applied to any fixed moment in time as well:
>
> 1972-05-20T17:33:18.772Z+6MONTHS+3DAYS/DAY

Quoted from [Apache Solr Reference Guide - Working with Dates](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Working+with+Dates)